# Spark.unmap() is creating CORS issue while unmapping an API

Tags: spark-java

It seems like the Spark.unmap(path) is creating the CORS issue. After using unmap, the request from the application running on localhost is not accepted by the SparkJava server, and it seems like its CORS policy gets distracted.

When I restart the server, everything starts working fine again. The disabled plugin API remains disabled. No issue if I enable them. But the issue will come again if I disable (unmap) any of the plugin API.